# I want optimized query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @cid int=1
DECLARE @datee date='2016-01-25';

WITH dl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            dl.imei,
            dl.vname,
            dl.driver,
            dl.mobileno
    FROM devices_list dl 
    WHERE dl.cid=@cid
),
gd AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer,
            MIN(b.odometer) minod 
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = @datee
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd1 AS (    
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer,
            MIN(b.odometer) minod2
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = DATEADD(day,-1,@datee)
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd2 AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = DATEADD(day,-7,@datee)
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd3 AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MIN(b.odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM')=FORMAT(@datee,'yyyy-MM') 
    GROUP BY b.imei
)

SELECT  dl.imei,
        dl.vname,
        dl.driver,
        dl.mobileno,
        gd.odometer,
        (gd.odometer-gd.minod) today,
        (gd1.odometer-gd1.minod2) yesterday,
        (gd.odometer-gd2.odometer) last7days,
        (gd.odometer-gd3.odometer) thismonth 
FROM dl 
LEFT JOIN gd ON dl.imei=gd.imei
LEFT JOIN gd1 ON dl.imei=gd1.imei
LEFT JOIN gd2 ON dl.imei=gd2.imei
LEFT JOIN gd3 ON dl.imei=gd3.imei;
```

Above query working well, but it taking too much time in execution. so please suggest me an optimized query.
[image: Result of My Query]

Comment: Show execution plan please. Also quantify your information. What is too long, how much data is there etc. And kill the FORMAT thingies - they mean "no index use" the way you do them as they are non sargeable.

Comment: Often slow execution times are due to lack of indexes. Do you have indexes where they need to be?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder Even if he has indices, the query conditions are non sargeable - so indices will not be used.

Comment: @TomTom am executing this query in stored procedure. i have around 5 milion records in gpsdata table.

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder i have id field for index.

Comment: Yeah, but you STILL show no execution plan. Do your homework - that is the first thing you grab. And LEARN TO USE A DATABASE - Indices should not be only on the ID field.

Comment: @SKYogi, slqserver handles `cast(... as date)` well without loosing indexes. Also you may circumvent time existence in your `packettime` column with applying appropriate filter, e.g.: `b.packettime >= @date and b.packettime < @date+1`

Comment: also you can suppress some of subqueries, make one subquery with wider date range and conditional aggregation `min(case when packetdate <> ... then b.odometer else null end)`

Comment: @Ivan CAST AS DATE can still use an index, sure. But it's an exception [not worth learning, using, or advocating IMHO](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the link! Good research.

Comment: add more columns to your table rather than calculating things like this FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd')

Answer (score 0):

This should work better for you:

```
DECLARE @cid int=1
DECLARE @datee date='2016-01-25';

WITH dl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            dl.imei,
            dl.vname,
            dl.driver,
            dl.mobileno
    FROM devices_list dl 
    WHERE dl.cid=@cid
),
gd AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer,
            MIN(b.odometer) minod 
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = @datee
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd1 AS (    
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer,
            MIN(b.odometer) minod2
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = DATEADD(day,-1,@datee)
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd2 AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = DATEADD(day,-7,@datee)
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
gd3 AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MIN(b.odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata b 
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM')=FORMAT(@datee,'yyyy-MM') 
    GROUP BY b.imei
)

SELECT  dl.imei,
        dl.vname,
        dl.driver,
        dl.mobileno,
        gd.odometer,
        (gd.odometer-gd.minod) today,
        (gd1.odometer-gd1.minod2) yesterday,
        (gd.odometer-gd2.odometer) last7days,
        (gd.odometer-gd3.odometer) thismonth 
FROM dl 
LEFT JOIN gd ON dl.imei=gd.imei
LEFT JOIN gd1 ON dl.imei=gd1.imei
LEFT JOIN gd2 ON dl.imei=gd2.imei
LEFT JOIN gd3 ON dl.imei=gd3.imei;
```

Comment: Next time edit the question with clean code. Please delete this, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your queries, you are querying the whole gpsdata table and filter the result on the JOINs using `LEFT JOIN gd ON dl.imei=gd.imei`. I believe you should try to reduce the number of rows processed from the queries on gpsdata.

To take some advantage from this, you should have a index on imei field.

Maybe this work for you:

```
DECLARE @cid int=1
DECLARE @datee date='2016-01-25';

   --Create a temp table to store the devices list
   SELECT DISTINCT
            dl.imei,
            dl.vname,
            dl.driver,
            dl.mobileno
    INTO #TMP
    FROM devices_list dl 
    WHERE dl.cid=@cid

WITH dl AS (
    --Load from the temp table
    SELECT DISTINCT
            dl.imei,
            dl.vname,
            dl.driver,
            dl.mobileno
    FROM #TMP
),
gd AS (
    SELECT  b.imei,
            MAX(b.odometer) odometer,
            MIN(b.odometer) minod 
    FROM gpsdata b 
    --Join to the temp table to reduce the number of rows processed
    INNER JOIN #TMP ON b.imei = #TMP.imei
    WHERE FORMAT(b.packettime,'yyyy-MM-dd') = @datee
    GROUP BY b.imei
),
. . . 

SELECT  dl.imei,
        dl.vname,
        dl.driver,
        dl.mobileno,
        gd.odometer,
        (gd.odometer-gd.minod) today,
        (gd1.odometer-gd1.minod2) yesterday,
        (gd.odometer-gd2.odometer) last7days,
        (gd.odometer-gd3.odometer) thismonth 
FROM dl 
LEFT JOIN gd ON dl.imei=gd.imei
LEFT JOIN gd1 ON dl.imei=gd1.imei
LEFT JOIN gd2 ON dl.imei=gd2.imei
LEFT JOIN gd3 ON dl.imei=gd3.imei;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @cid int=1
 DECLARE @datee date='2016-01-25';

 SELECT  dl.imei,
         dl.vname,
         dl.driver,
         dl.mobileno,
         gd.odometer,
         (gd.odometer-gd.minod) today,
         (gd1.odometer-gd1.minod2) yesterday,
         (gd.odometer-gd2.odometer) last7days,
         (gd.odometer-gd3.odometer) thismonth 
 FROM
 ( SELECT DISTINCT
            imei,
            vname,
            driver,
            mobileno
    FROM devices_list  
    WHERE cid=@cid ) as dl LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT  imei,
           MAX(odometer) odometer,
           MIN(odometer) minod 
    FROM gpsdata  
    --WHERE cast(packettime as datetime) = @datee
    WHERE packettime  = @datee
    GROUP BY imei
 ) as gd 
 ON dl.imei=gd.imei  LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT  imei,
            MAX(odometer) odometer,
            MIN(odometer) minod2
    FROM gpsdata  
    WHERE packettime = DATEADD(day,-1,@datee)
    GROUP BY imei
 ) as gd1 
 ON dl.imei=gd1.imei LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT  imei,
           MAX(odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata  
    WHERE packettime = DATEADD(day,-7,@datee)
    GROUP BY imei
 ) as gd2 
 ON dl.imei=gd2.imei LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT  imei,
           MIN(odometer) odometer
    FROM gpsdata 
    --WHERE FORMAT(packettime,'yyyy-MM')=FORMAT(@datee,'yyyy-MM') 
    WHERE YEAR(packettime)=YEAR(@datee) 
    AND MONTH(packettime)=MONTH(@datee) 
    GROUP BY imei
 ) as gd3
 ON dl.imei=gd3.imei
```

I assumed packettime is already a datetime column. If not you have to cast it every time you use it.

You might as well want to consider creating an index on packettime that includes odometer and imei